# Substitution for INTERSECT in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to use an intersect query on phpMyAdmin but obviously it doesn't supports `INTERSECT`, at least I'm pretty sure it doesn't. This is the query I'm trying to use, but what is another way I could put it to where I don't use `INTERSECT`?

```
SELECT cust_code, cust_fname, cust_lname 
FROM lgcustomer join lginvoice USING (cust_code) WHERE employee_id = 83649
INTERSECT
SELECT cust_code, cust_fname, cust_lname 
FROM lgcustomer join lginvoice USING (cust_code) WHERE employee_id = 83677
ORDER BY cust_lname, cust_fname;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right, MySQL doesn't support INTERSECT.

```
SELECT cust_code, cust_fname, cust_lname 
FROM lgcustomer join lginvoice USING (cust_code) 
WHERE employee_id IN (83649, 83677)
GROUP BY cust_code, cust_fname, cust_lname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id) = 2
```

---

Update: MySQL 8.0.31 (released 2022-10-11) supports INTERSECT. See https://lefred.be/content/intersect-and-except-in-mysql-8-0/

Answer (score 0):

Use joins instead :

```
SELECT cust_code, cust_fname, cust_lname 
FROM lgcustomer 
join lginvoice l1 on l1.cust_code = lgcustomer.cust_code AND l1.employee_id = 83649
join lginvoice l2 on l2.cust_code = lgcustomer.cust_code AND l2.employee_id = 83677
```